# Send real time vidéo streaming from Raspberry Pi to Android App

Tags: android, python, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3

I'm going to be working on a project in which the  Pi will be taking real time video and sending it to an android app to view . 
Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Can you provide me some ressources or links which can help me? thank you.

Comment: Of course it is possible to do, but we're not here to code a working app for you or to find resources that you can easily find yourself.

Comment: that's not my question.I  didn't ask for "a working app", but just to give me some idea to begin with such as I'm a beginner ,and  thank you for your interraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I google your question for you and found this:
 [Web Cam streaming from Raspberry Pi to Android using streamer](http://sanjosetech.blogspot.se/2013/03/web-cam-streaming-from-raspberry-pi-to.html)

Complete with source code, youtube instructions and 70 comments in the View comments

I think I answered your Q?

Comment: Can you close the question by marking it as answered(the green check image).